# debugging gdb tui define new layout

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm trying to define an own new layout for the gdb tui mode (according to https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html#TUI-Commands, but everytime I enter the example (`tui new-layout example src 1 regs 1 status 0 cmd 1`) I get this error: `Undefined tui command: "new-layout example src 1 regs 1 status 0 cmd 1".  Try "help tui".`

Any suggestions, what might be wrong (I'm already in TUI mode (`tui enable`) when entering the command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issues as you. Doesn't seem like that feature is in 9.1 even though the documentation shows it.

I tried building the GDB snapshot release 10.0.50.20200305-git and it had the tui new-layout feature.

You can find the snapshot releases here:
ftp://sourceware.org/pub/gdb/snapshots/current/

Here is what I did:

```
cd ~/src
tar xf gdb-10.0.50.20200306.tar.xz
mkdir gdb
cd gdb
~/src/gdb-10.5.50.20200306/configure --enable-tui
make
 ~/src/gdb/gdb/gdb  --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.0.50.20200306-git
```

Then I just ran gdb from ~/src/gdb on an executable.
I could then do

```
tui new-layout example regs 19 src 21 cmd 20
```

However, it didn't persist after restarting gdb. 
But I could switch to it if I didn't exit.

```
layout asm
layout regs
layout example
```

Not sure if the layout is supposed to persist after exiting and starting?

Comment: As far as I know, this layout is not to be persistant, but you can put those commands into your `~/.gdbinit` ;)

Comment: I've got just one little problem with that snapshot, I get this error message: `elf.c:740:35: error: overflow in conversion from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ changes value from ‘num_group = 4294967295’ to ‘-1’ [-Werror=overflow]
  740 |     elf_tdata (abfd)->num_group = num_group = -1;` but it's just a snapshot, so I just wonder when how long it will take until this is in the official version too.

Comment: And, I just checked my local gdb documentation (`info gdb`) and there the paragraph with creating own layouts wasn't present, so I guess I simply have to wait or somwhoew get one of the newer snapshots working.

Comment: It's probably just a matter of time before the new version is released. Not sure about the error you're getting. I had to install some dependencies to get my build to work (libncurses-dev libncursesw5-dev and  libconfig-dev).

Comment: Hm, well maybe I'll try it again, checking the dependencies in advance, but as I'm on Arch Linux, I have really new packages so it shouldn't be long until I get the updated version (depending on how long it takes the gdb dev team to release it)

Comment: @JopeM What are the weight parameters `20`, `21`, `19` actually for? Documentation is really not good...

Comment: It's just the amount of screen each window takes relative to each other. 

"Each weight is an integer. It is the weight of this window relative to all the other windows in the layout. These numbers are used to calculate how much of the screen is given to each window." (25.5 TUI-specific Commands)